# How to add "360" to all negative numbers in a 2-D list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, nested

I am trying to create a nested for loop to loop through a 2D array and add "360" to all the negative numbers.

My 2D array or "var" looks like:

```
array([[  16,   15,   12,   15],
       [ -85,  -69,  -66,  -68],
       [ -86,  -67,  -64,  -65],
       [ -87,  -80,  -73,  -62],
       [ -23,  -17,  -15,  -13]])
```

My nested for loop looks like:

```
for row in var:
    for elem in row:
        if elem < 0:
            elem + 360
print(var)
```

But I am having no luck. Any help with fixing the for loop and printing out the result would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: `elem + 360` increases the value by 360 and then promptly ignores the new value. You aren't *doing* anything with `elem + 360`. You are just computing it then discarding the computed value.

Comment: `[[e + 360 if e < 0 else e for e in row] for row in var]`

Comment: Wait, `array`? Are you using NumPy? That wasn't clear from your original question. If you're using a major library that adds its own data types please make sure to include a relevant tag as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki.

Comment: Alternatively if these are degrees and your goal is just to normalize them to a range from 0 to 359, the better solution is `[[e % 360 for e in row] for row in var]`

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy for filtering and adding:

```
var[var<0] += 360
```

output:

```
array([[ 16,  15,  12,  15],
       [275, 291, 294, 292],
       [274, 293, 296, 295],
       [273, 280, 287, 298],
       [337, 343, 345, 347]])
```